# Enrolled faceid on XCUITest/XCTest scenario

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, xctest, xcuitest

I'm searching for a updated solution or official solution for we enrolled and do the matching face using faceid for automation on XCTest/XCUITest. If it's possible something with swift.

Thanks.

- Enrolled the faceid
- Do login on the application
- Match face using iOS faceid

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with unit tests by faking the interactions with FaceID. Then you can write tests for authorized and not authorized cases.

For UI tests, you can't inject fakes. The best you can do is avoid this flow.